# LDAP Support for the new Authentication System in VS2013 (based on owin (owin.org) )

Tags: .net, ldap, visual-studio-2013, owin

Do we know how to implement LDAP support for the new authentication system introduced in VS 2013 which is based on owin.org .

I have written my own provider using Forms authentication but it doesnt work any more.

Any ways to extend this will also be highly welcome. All I see is built in support for a lot of oauth providers like Google, Twitter and Facebook.

Comment: Did you check out this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/21/using-claims-in-your-web-app-is-easier-with-the-new-owin-security-components.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy. You simply need to override the [CheckPasswordAsync method in the provided UserManager](http://willwebforfood.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/owin-and-active-directory/). (Full disclosure, that's my blog post).

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> {
//...SNIP...
    public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => {
            _context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            return _context.ValidateCredentials(user.UserName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate)
        });
    }
}
```

That's a very naiive method, but it should work.

Comment: Using `Task.Run` will hurt performance on ASP.NET. Use `Task.FromResult` to return a completed `Task` instead.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Do you have a link to more info about the performance of Tak.Run vs Task.FromResult?

Comment: I have several on my [curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general). You can find a lot more on the [PFX Team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/) and [Stephen Clearly's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/). Why do you think calling `Task.Run` on an ASP.NET application is any good?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. In my login controller I use the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync and this method never calls UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync. Is some configuration that allow this methods to communicate?

Comment: @miguelbgouveia Did you do anything to Startup.Auth.cs?

Comment: In the Startup.Auth.cs I add the code: app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)); as you said in your blog "MVC 5, OWIN and Active Directory Authentication".